# Error [ERR_INTERNAL_ASSERTION]: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_THIS]: Value of "this" must be of type EventTarget

Tags: react-native, redux, axios

Getting ERR_INVALID_THIS on any API call, sometimes it works and  sometimes not works,

```
error:
{name: 'Error', message: 'TypeError [ERR_INVALID_THIS]: Value of "this…ce at https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues\n', stack: 'Error [ERR_INTERNAL_ASSERTION]: TypeError [ER…og (node:internal/console/constructor:360:61)', code: 'ERR_INTERNAL_ASSERTION'}
code:
'ERR_INTERNAL_ASSERTION'
message:
'TypeError [ERR_INVALID_THIS]: Value of "this" must be of type EventTarget\n    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)\n    at EventTarget.[nodejs.util.inspect.custom] (node:internal/event_target:666:13)\n    at formatValue (node:internal/util/inspect:782:19)\n    at formatProperty (node:internal/util/inspect:1819:11)\n    at formatRaw (node:internal/util/inspect:1030:9)\n    at formatValue (node:internal/util/inspect:817:10)\n    at inspect (node:internal/util/inspect:347:10)\n    at formatWithOptionsInternal (node:internal/util/inspect:2167:40)\n    at formatWithOptions (node:internal/util/inspect:2029:10)\n    at console.value (node:internal/console/constructor:324:14)\nThis is caused by either a bug in Node.js or incorrect usage of Node.js internals.\nPlease open an issue with this stack trace at https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues\n'
name:
'Error'
stack:
'Error [ERR_INTERNAL_ASSERTION]: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_THIS]: Value of "this" must be of type EventTarget\n    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:372:5)\n
```

Answer (score 2):

I also face this issue sometimes whenever I've Debugger enabled in the Vs Code and I console.log(error)
It is not related to any library it is just because you have paased a lots of arguments in the consol.log() or warn function
because axios error return a lot of cofigs in the error